# Graphicspath and standalone

Tags: graphics, errors, standalone, includegraphics, compilation-error

I have a standalone setup with the following file structure

```
A
├── A.tex
└── sections
    ├── B
    │   ├── Bimages
    │   │   └── cat.png
    │   └── B.tex
    └── C
        ├── Cimages
        └── C.tex
```

I have a main tex file called A and two subfiles B and C, such that the content of A is a title page then B and C concatenated. B has its own images directory, which is referenced in B.tex using `\graphicspath{ {./Bimages/} }` and C similarly has ./Cimages/. B and C compile separately perfectly well, however, when I compile A, I get `LaTeX Warning: File Bimages/cat.png not found on input line 89.`

Is this expected behaviour with standalone? Will it not account for relative file paths in subdirectories? If so, is there a way to work around this such that I can organise my images into separate folders(preferably without having to do `\graphicspath{ {./sections/B/Bimages} {./sections/C/Cimages} }` in A.tex, as I may have many more similar directories in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Because your problem is interesting and somebody may have a similar problem when using OpTeX, I give OpTeX solution here. Note, that OpTeX isn't LaTeX and if you are using LaTeX then my answer isn't for you.

OpTeX declares for including graphics the token register `\picdir` and, of course, there is an equivalent control sequence `\_picdir` which is the same token register. Suppose, that you have `\picdir{Bimages/}` in the `B.tex` file and `\picdir{Cimages/}` in the `C.tex` file. Then you can run OpTeX on `B.tex` or `C.tex` standalone.

In the main file `A.tex`, you can deactivate the `\picdir` and use only `\_picdir`. A part of `A.tex` can look like this:

```
\let\picdir=\ignoreit
\_picdir{B/Bimages/}
\input B/B.tex
\_picdir{C/Cimages/}
\input C/C.tex
\bye
```

Answer (score 0):

you might want to change the way you import your subfiles

`\input` just copies the text content of B.tex into A.tex before compiling.
That makes A look for the graphicspath in it's home directory (which is /A/)

`\include` (I think) creates aux files for every sub-file and therefore might be able to find the correct subpath (for example /A/B/Bimages/)

**I DID NOT TEST THIS!**

see [this](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/thesis/html/include.html) for reference

---

If that does not do the trick, then you could maybe switch to using global paths for your images
(like `"~/foo/bar/A/B/Bimages/"` instead of `"./B/Bimages/"`).